# CodeIgniter POST/GET default value

Tags: forms, codeigniter, post

Can I set default value for POST/GET data if it's empty/false, something like

```
$this->input->post("varname", "value-if-falsy")
```

?

So I don't have to code like

```
$a = $this->input->post("varname") ? 
     $this->input->post("varname") :
     "value-if-falsy"
```

Comment: if you want to "value-if-falsy" as "" then it ll automatically do it

Comment: otherwise you can do like this just for shorten, $a = $this->input->post("varname") ; $a=(empty($a))?"value-if-falsy":$a;

Comment: if you are saving value to db you can set default value there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to override the default behavior.

In `application/core` create `MY_Input.php`

```php
class MY_Input extends CI_Input
{
    function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = FALSE, $default_value = NULL)
    {
        // Check if a field has been provided
        if ($index === NULL AND ! empty($_POST))
        {
            $post = array();

            // Loop through the full _POST array and return it
            foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key)
            {
                $post[$key] = $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $key, $xss_clean);
            }

            return $post;
        }

        $ret_val = $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean);
        if(!$ret_val)
            $ret_val = $default_value;

        return $ret_val;
    }
}
```

And then in your controller :

```
$this->input->post("varname", "", "value-if-falsy")
```

Comment: I already created MY_Input class of my own before, in case there is no built-in way to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you rewrite the default method contents and don't call `parent::post($index, $xss_clean)`?

Comment: @fabsn Just for educational purpose if I can say it that way. But yes you are absolutely right, we can just do a test on `parent::post()` and return the default parameters if false.

Answer (score 8):

Just found out not very long ago that I can also use `?:`, eg.

```
$name = $this->input->post('name') ?: 'defaultvalue';
```

Comment: I believe nowadays this should be the accepted answer. It's the more concise way of doing it *without* creating a MY_Input class.

Comment: The accepted one is exactly what I thought at the time, and this answer above (by me) is very new. So I keep the old accepted answer for respect and being grateful, though now I always use this one :-)

Answer (score 4):

It works for me, I have used the @AdrienXL trick.

Just create your `application/core/MY_Input.php` file and call the parent method (you can find this methods inside CodeIgniter system folder `system/core/Input.php`:

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Input extends CI_Input
{
    function post($index = NULL, $default_value = NULL, $xss_clean = FALSE)
    {
        $value = parent::post($index, $xss_clean);

        return ($value) ? $value : $default_value;
    }

    function get($index = NULL, $default_value = NULL, $xss_clean = FALSE)
    {
        $value = parent::get($index, $xss_clean);

        return ($value) ? $value : $default_value;
    }
}
```

So, when call the method, pass the default value:

```
$variable = $this->input->post("varname", "value-if-falsy");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code block as below

```
public function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = NULL, $default_value = NULL  )
{
    if( is_null( $value = $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean ) ) ){
        return $default_value;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code before set_rules

```
empty($_POST['varname']) ? $_POST['varname'] = 'value if empty' : 0;
```

Comment: can `empty($_POST['varname']) AND $_POST['varname']="value if false` run without error?